# Get list of plugins requiring updates programmatically

Tags: wordpress

I know there is the `get_plugins()` function to get all plugins, but I want to know if there's a way to get a list of all plugins that have updates, and their current and next versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`wp_get_update_data()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_update_data/) or use the code this function uses to get only the available plugin updates:

```
$update_plugins = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );
if ( ! empty( $update_plugins->response ) )
    var_dump( $update_plugins->response );
```

I suppose the response has the version info you need.